# mysql use return value in same procedure

Tags: mysql

my query execute and return a value and i need to use the return value in the same procedure, how to use it ?

my code is

```
  set @table_name_count = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) into @xcount ', CONCAT( ' FROM ' ) , concat( table_name),concat( ' where issueNumber=',concat('30030'),concat( ' and ISSNcode='),CONCAT('112640402')));

     PREPARE statement from @table_name_count;
     EXECUTE statement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
     select 'hello4' from dual;
     IF xcount > 0 and xcount<>NULL THEN
       DELETE from table_name where issueNumber='30030' and ISSNcode='112640402' ;
     END IF  ;
```

here i need to use the @xcount in the conditions

```
IF xcount > 0 and xcount<>NULL THEN
   DELETE from table_name where issueNumber='30030' and ISSNcode='112640402' ;
 END IF  ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot `@` before the variable name since you're dealing with user(session) variables. Your `IF` statement should like this

```
IF @xcount > 0 THEN
   ^
```

You don't need to check for `NULL` since `COUNT()` always returns a value.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311f4/1)** demo

---

Now **there is no point** in making such a check for record(s) existence before issuing `DELETE`.
If there are no rows matching conditions in `WHERE` clause of `DELETE` statement it just won't  do anything and won't produce any error.

Therefore you can ditch all the code except for `DELETE` statement.